# Rails: validate number of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

How do you write validations for a number of associations that is externally defined? I've so far written something like this:

```
class Document
  validate :publication_count

  private

  def publication_count
    if publications.count > template.component_count
      errors.add(:articles, 'too many')
    elsif publications.count < template.component_count
      errors.add(:articles, 'not enough')
    end
  end
```

Both `publications` and `template` are associations. I just get a rollback error with this code, even though the record should be valid.

Comment: seems correct... put logger in first line of method `validate_tags`, printing count of `publications` and `template` and see if they are equal or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears correct, so it seems likely that the associations aren't being set or saved correctly.

Did you check that:

- `publications` and `template` are both assigned to the `Document` instance before you save?
- the rollback error isn't for a different reason, like uniqueness failure?
- this is the actual validation that's failing rather than another one?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's tripping the `not enough` error message which is making me think I'm trying to validate too early, i.e., _before_ the `publications` record exists. I'll need to validate _after_ the `publications` records are saved, which is when a `Document` is created. Is that even possible in this situation?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Eric I see three potential answers to the question in his post.

Comment: You didn't answer any of them.

Comment: @Eric: IMO, the question (quoting from OP) is "How do you write validations for a number of associations that is externally defined?". I answered that with "Your code appears correct, so it seems likely that the associations aren't being set or saved correctly."